# Unexpected boot sequence with two cloned hard drives

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive

For redundancy purposes, my computer has two identical hard drives.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and Grub in /dev/sda.

I cloned /dev/sda to /dev/sdb (I used [FOG](https://fogproject.org/))

When I change the primary hard drive in the BIOS I don't always get that hard drive to boot. It doesn't always start the Grub installed in this "primary hard drive".

I have read some information about the boot sequence

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub.html

http://www.golinuxhub.com/2014/03/step-by-step-linux-boot-process.html

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/linux-boot-process/

but I'm still unable to consistently boot from the drive I want. My fstab uses the UUID.

After the clone, the partitions in sda and sdb have the same UUID. 
I changed the UUID of the partions in /dev/sdbx with

```
tune2fs -U random /dev/sdbx
```

And updated the /etc/fstab file in /dev/sdb1 to use the new UUIDs. I then updated grub with

```
sudo update-grub
```

And I installed it in both hard drives:

```
sudo install-grub /dev/sda
sudo install-grub /dev/sdb
```

When I boot again, it doesn't matter if I choose the first (sda) or the fourth (sdb) option in Grub, it always boots from sda.

The file /boot/grub/grub.cfg uses the UUID. could this be related to my problem?

Comment: You probably need to look at the UUID's and change them to something new for your cloned harddrive; grub will probably refer to the UUID and just use a 'first come first serve' principle.
You can change the UUID's with a live-cd with gparted, after which you will have to change the /boot/grub/grub.cfg accordingly (which, in this case, is allowed IMO)

Comment: The decision which drive is `sda` and which drive is `sdb` depends on the ports the drives are connected to. If you have four SATA-ports, the drive connected to the first port is `sda`. Numbering of ports is different on motherboards, may be port0-3 or port1-4. In the first case port0 is `sda`, in second case port1 is `sda`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the cloned drive to boot you need to reinstall Grub on this drive.
Boot to `sda` and when the Grub-menu appears choose Ubuntu installed on 'sdb' to start. then open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the command

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```

This will reinstall Grub to the MBR of `sdb` and this Grub points to the partition where Ubuntu is installed on the same drive. The other drive `sda` will be untouched and will work like before.

Checking the UUID's of the partitions on `sdb` with

```
sudo blkid
```

as mentioned in the comment of twicejr is a good idea, probably you have to adapt the UUID's in `/etc/fstab` on `sdb`.

That's it, now you should be able to boot directly to `sdb` choosing this drive as first drive in the boot-order in BIOS.

Note: This is only valid if your Ubuntu is installed in legacy-mode ( good old BIOS-mode). In UEFI-mode it would be very different!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated the question with more details about how these steps didn't work for me.